# HTML5 Audio Control on Mobile Safari (iPhone, ios 11)

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, ios11

I am trying to figure out why the HTML5 audio control will not work on iPhone and other devices running ios 11 when playing a live Shoutcast stream. I have tried it two ways and it works on desktop computer and android but not ios 11.

```
    <audio controls>
           <source src="http://s4.viastreaming.net:7590/;" type="audio/mpeg;"></source>
           Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <audio controls>
           <source src="http://s4.viastreaming.net:7590/;listen.m3u" type="audio/mpeg;"></source>
           Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ab7691/8o86v4xp/5/

How can we get it to work for ios 11 devices?